# Regular expression for GA, containing a string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

My regular expression skills are naive at best.
I'm trying to generate a report in `Google Analytics`. I would like to filter this report on URL that meet the following criteria:

```
(.+)/book/<contains the case insensitive word 'test'>
```

This translates to:

- URL may start with anything
- URL should have 'book' after the first `/`
- URL should contain the case insensitive keyword 'test', after the second `/`. There may be characters before and after the keyword 'test'

I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
(.+)/book/(\btest\b)
```

Examples of acceptable URLs:

http://website.com/book/Biology-Tests/section/2.6/

http://website.com/book/Geometry-Test/section/3.9/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share a few examples of the string you need ?

Comment: Try `^/book/(?i).*test`. Or `^/book/(?i:.*test)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: These are both invalid expressions

Comment: See the answer below, it should work even if the inplace modifiers or modifier groups  are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^/book/.*[tT][Ee][Ss][Tt]
```

It will match a URL that right after the host part contains the `book` (case sensitive) subpath, and then, after any 0+ chars (`.*`) contains a case insensitive word `test`. If the word `test` must be a whole word, enclose with word boundaries: `^/book/.*\b[tT][Ee][Ss][Tt]\b`.

Note that to match `test` and `tests`, the `\b` can only be used *in front* of the word:

```
^/book/.*\b[tT][Ee][Ss][Tt]
```

or use an optional subpattern before the trailing word boundary:

```
^/book/.*\b[tT][Ee][Ss][Tt][sS]?\b
                           ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Tested both at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/za2o3a/1) and [Google Analytics Regular Expression Tester](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Fun Fact: Google Analytics doesn't care about case insensitivity. Icould make it work just using 'test', without the square barces.

Comment: Oh, I think it is true as the GA regex tester also matches without the `[]`. It seems that the literal string in the GA pattern is case insensitive, but if you enclose a char with `[]`, it becomes case sensitive (`[t][e][s][t]` will only match `test`, not `Test`). Found some nice explanations [here](http://www.shimonsandler.com/regex-in-google-analytics/).